# What is the best way to enable the next Input box when another Input box is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attr, prop

I have something similar to this:

```
<input id="1" type="text"></input>
<input id="2" type="text" disabled></input>
```

When I change the contents of id="1" I want to enable id="2". I can get it to work in this format, however, I need it to be in a specific function instead of a generic input onchange event because this page has numerous inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input").change(function(){
  $(this).next().prop("disabled", false); // Element(s) are now enabled.
 });
});
```

I believe my issue is passing "this" information to be able to change the next element. I have tried the below lines of code but am unable to get them to work. Ignore the alerts I placed in there, I was just trying to see what information was passed. Also, I am passing a string with the onchange event as well.

```
$(el.id).next().prop("disabled", false);

function myFunction (str, el) {
 var newId = el.id;
 alert(newId);
 $(newId).next().prop("disabled", false);
}

function myFunction (str, id) {
 $(id).next().prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Updated Code:

```
  function Update(str, el){
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    var newId = el.id;
                    alert(newId);
                    $(newId).next().prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else {

        }
      }
     };
    var Info = str;
    var queryString = Info;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","Reduced.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(queryString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keyup` event listener instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
  $(this).next().prop("disabled", false); // Element(s) are now enabled.
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: The input type is text. Which changing that to type=text doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, my original answer was checkbox. I was just using a checkbox for testing. My answer is modified appropriately.

Comment: It would need to stay as "change" instead of "keyup". I can make it work with that, but it is still somewhat of a work-around. I need it within a function as I am passing a string with the onchange event.